# Unsupported minor version 51

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

I cannot get the following command to run successfully on my Yosemite 10.10.5 machine.

> mvn -version

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

I've googled around and every indicates its a problem with my JAVA_HOME directory but I cannot figure out the problem.  The directory looks set properly here:

> MacBook-Air:~ user$ java -version
>   java version "1.8.0_40"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27) 
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
>
> MacBook-Air:~ user$ echo $JAVA_HOME
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

my bash_profile:

> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
>   M2_HOME=/usr/local/opt/maven/libexec
>   M2=/usr/local/opt/maven/libexec/bin
>   PATH=/usr/local/opt/maven/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Thats probably the first thread I found and if it had worked, we wouldn't be here right now

Comment: Start by making sure that `mvn` is the real thing, with `type mvn`. This should give you a path to a shell script. Take a look at that script, and verify that it hasn't been mucked with (compare to a fresh download). Assuming it's the same, look at the configuration files that it loads (`/etc/mavenrc` and `"$HOME/.mavenrc` on my machine). You could also try `echo $JAVA_HOME` inside this script.

Comment: Also, take a look at `$HOME/.bashrc` to see if it changes `JAVA_HOME`. Based on the error message, you're running Java 6, not 8, regardless of what happens from the command-line. There will be a reason somewhere in your exec chain.

Comment: You are trying to run a Java-8 compiled file in a Java-7 VM.